# How to extract a word from a line?

Tags: python, set

I've started python course not so long time ago.

I have a file "input.txt" with lines (id, animal, gender, name, date of birth, date arrived to the zoo):

```
7910 leopard male Leo 04.06.2001 05.15.2010. 
9315 cat male Hiha 01.04.2004 03.24.2012. 
2226 leopard female Lia 07.28.2007 08.24.2019.
```

I need to extract from each line the kind of animal and then sort kinds into the list by length:

```
cat
leopard
```

I had some thoughts but Idk how to extract kind of an animal from each line

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
    animals = set()
    for line in file.readlines():

animals.add(x)
sorted(animals, key=lambda x: len(x))
print(animals)
```

Comment: Have you tried the string.split() method?   https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split

Comment: You probably want `animals.sort(key=...)` instead of `sorted(animals, key=...)` since you want to sort in place

Answer (score 1):

I think this can work:

```py
>>> file = open('input.txt', 'r')
>>> {line.split()[1] for line in file.readlines()}
{'leopard', 'cat'}
```

While the second word of each line is the kind of that animal, accessing the `1` index of it can give you the kind.